# Modify/ access matrix content C++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have this code of a class representing a matrix:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    int** M;
    int n, m;
public:
    Matrix(int _n, int _m, int v) {
        n = _n;
        m = _m;

        M = new int*[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            M[i] = new int[m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                M[i][j] = v;
        }
    }

    int operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col) {
        return this -> M[row][col];
    }

    void set(int i, int j, int v) {
        M[i][j] = v;
    }
};
```

I can *not* change the content of a cell when I use this class in the `main` function or within another class. I can only access/diplay a cell thanks to `operator()`, but I can not change its value unless I use the method `set()`.

I would like to know if there is a why? Maybe using other methods or operators, to access and modify the content of a cell outside the class `Matrix`?

Just like this:

```
Matrix m(4,4,0);
m(2,2) = 10000; // ERROR!
```

and *not*

```
m.set(2,2,10000);
```

Comment: Return a reference to the element. But seriously, implement the matrix with a single block of data. No point in using a dynamic array of dynamic arrays here.

Comment: To add on to what @juanchopanza you would want to a method with signature `int& operator()( int x, int y )`

Answer (score 1):

You have made `int **M` a private variable. The idea of a private variable is that you explicitly cannot change it outside of the class (see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/). You can do one of two things:

1. Return a reference to the element as:

   `int &operator() (unsigned row, unsigned col)
   {
       return M[row][col];
   }`
2. Make `int **M` a public variable. This will allow you to access `m.M[2][2]` in main.cpp as normal.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works...  Could you just explain more in detail why if I return a reference/ address works while if I would return the value it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: When you have a private variable, only the class is allowed to change it directly. As such, if you say `m.M[2][2] = 3;` while it is still private, your compiler will yell at you. When you pass the reference, however, you aren't directly changing `m.M`, you are changing a reference to it.